# IPhone apps for a programmer to increase productivity

Tags: iphone, mobile-phones

I am looking for mobile apps that will help me be more productive and be all around more useful as a programmer. I have the Dropbox app and Awesome Note. As a programmer what apps or tools do you use on your IPhone/IPod that help you be more productive etc...?

Ideally I am looking for SRC control, SSH tools, Web development-related apps etc.

Comment: I would advise changing this to community wiki.

Answer (score 2):

[AppSales](http://github.com/omz/AppSales-Mobile) keeps track of sales data and user reviews.

Comment: Thanks, looks like a good app.

Answer (score 1):

[iSimulate](http://www.vimov.com/isimulate/) lets you send a lot of sensor and input data from your device to the simulator - so for example you can get proper iPhone GPS callbacks with your real location in the simulator instead of on the device.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [CodeToGo](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/codetogo/id382677229?mt=8) IApp built upon [IdeoneAPI](http://ideone.com) (a multicompiler)
which might be of your interest and possibly  [another two](http://www.readwriteweb.com/hack/2010/12/code-editors-for-the-ipad.php) (Gusto and Textastic via ReadWriteHack).